# minimizing kullback-leiber for normal-gamma

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, optimization, machine-learning

Considering two continuous probability distributions q(x) and p(x),  The Kullback leiber Divergence is defined as the measure of the information lost when q(x) is used to approximate p(x).
\begin{equation*}
    KL (p(x)|| q(x)) = \int_{R} p(x) \ln \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} dx
\end{equation*}

A distributions in the exponential family can be written as :
\begin{equation*}
    p_\theta(x) = \frac{1}{Z(\theta)} exp(\theta^T \phi (x))
\end{equation*}
where $\phi(x)$ is the vector of the natural statistics of x and $Z(\theta) = \int_ exp(\theta^T \phi(x)) dx$ .

My goal is to prove that for the special case of the  normal-gamma distribution.
$$(X,T) - NormalGamma(\mu, \lambda,\alpha,\beta)$$
with pdf:
$$
f(x,t;\mu,\lambda,\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\beta^\alpha \sqrt{\lambda}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\sqrt{2\pi}} t^{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\beta t} \exp\left(-\frac{\lambda t(x-\mu)^2}{2} \right).
$$
we have the following theorem:
the distribution $p_{\theta*}$ which minimises the Kullback-Leibler divergence for the normal inverse gamma distribution with probability distribution $p_\theta$ is given by :
\begin{equation*}
    E_{p_{\theta^*}(x)}[\phi(x)] =  E_{p_{(x)}}[\phi(x)]
\end{equation*}

This will imply finding $\theta^*$ such that $\nabla_\theta f(\theta^*) =0$
Then I will need to find the hessian to proof that $\theta^*$ is actually the minimum.
My problem is that I was not able to realize those derivation successfully.
Could anyone help me please?